# SharePoint online REST API: how to get custom field list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

I also want to get the custom columns via REST, If you fire up Google Postman or Advanced REST Api client you can get a desired json response for the query below.

```
https://mydev/sites/site1/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?@target='https://mydev/sites/site2/subsiteBlog'
```

But in the Post's list I made a custom column and the custom field doesn't come with that response, How can I get the value from this field using a rest api call ?

Comment: I get all fields in a list with this url (https://mydev/sites/site/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Custom List')/Fields)

Comment: hi @Gol.D, thanks for the replay, yeah /fields gives me the info about the fields(metadata) but what I need is the values of the fields for every item comming in the response when I do the call, e.g by default the list have some columns, but I've add it one more let's say **customColumn1**, when I do the call **customColumn1** doesn´t appear in the response.

Answer (score 1):

add a `$select=myfield1,myfield2,etc` onto your REST url.  Note that once you add the `$select` parameter, only the fields you explicitly select will be returned.  Without a `$select` parameter, all built-in fields are returned.

See official doc on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx#sectionSection0)